# Error in loading database entries into lists

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Nike/test_two.py", line 43, in <module>
do_query()
File "/home/pi/Nike/test_two.py", line 33, in do_query
for(Product,Bin,Size,Color) in records:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Code:

```
def do_query():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('test_db.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TESTER ORDER BY CheckNum")
    records = cursor.fetchall()

    for(Product,Bin,Size,Color) in records:
        row_1.append(Product)
        row_2.append(Bin)
        row_3.append(Size)
        row_4.append(Color)

    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

do_query()
```

I'm trying to load each column of a table into seperate python list. I am using Python, and sqlite3. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Well, do you have exactly four columns in your `TESTER` table? If not, you can't write the `for` loop the way you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using "SELECT *" which will return every column from the table. My guess is that the table in question contains more columns then the 4 you specified.

A better way would actually be specifying in the SQL which columns you want so that your code will not break if columns are added to the database.

Something like "SELECT col1, col2 FROM table"

You can run the sqlite3 tool on the db file and then view the table schema with ".schema <table_name>"

Comment: Oh that ended up working perfectly. I'm fairly new to coding, so wasn't aware the * pulls all from the database.